# Validating BigDecimal data type for nulls In Java

Tags: java, validation, bigdecimal

I am trying to validate for NULLs on a data type BigDecimal in java. I am able to validate for 0 value however NULL's is resulting in a **NULL Point Exception**. Should I handle the validation of this datatype in an exception or is there some calculation I can preform on the data to validate it. Under is an example of what i have done so far:

```
 if(crime.getCrimeLatLocation() != null  & crime.getCrimeLongLocation() != null || crime.getCrimeLatLocation().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0 & crime.getCrimeLongLocation().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0){

     logger.info('Valid Data');
    }
```

Comment: You have two `&` - should they be `&&` - boolean logic should work better with that change.  Also the boolean logic would probably be more clear and possibly work better if you separate the lat/long comparisons.  Also instead of using `compareTo() != 0`, you probably want to use `equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)`.

Comment: @RobI you should not use `.equals` with `BigDecimal` as this takes precision into account, so `0.00` does not `equals` `0`. `compareTo` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `||` should be an `&&` - what's happening is that when you pass in a null value it's evaluating to false in the first two conditions, but then it's proceeding on to the third and fourth conditions and resulting in an exception.  If you change the `||` to an `&&` then short circuit evaluation will prevent the third and fourth conditions from evaluating.

Be certain to use a `&&` and not a `&` - the former uses short-circuit evaluation, but the latter would force the third and fourth conditions to evaluate and you'll get a null pointer exception again.  `condition1 && condition2` says "return false if condition1 is false, else evaluate condition2" - if condition1 is false then condition2 is never evaluated.  In contrast, `condition1 & condition2` will always evaluate both conditions.  The only reason to use `&` is if the conditions have side-effects.  Likewise, `condition1 || condition2` will not evaluate condition2 if condition1 is true, but `|` will always evaluate both conditions.

Answer (score 3):

If your main goal is validating BigDecimal dataType for nulls, then just make a comparison;

```
yourBigDecimal != null.
```

The above statement is enough for comparison and checking.

Answer (score 1):

Your test here

```
if(crime.getCrimeLatLocation() != null  & crime.getCrimeLongLocation() != null 
|| crime.getCrimeLatLocation().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0 & crime.getCrimeLongLocation().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0)
```

Uses binary not boolean operators, change this to

```
if((crime.getCrimeLatLocation() != null  && crime.getCrimeLatLocation().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0) 
|| (crime.getCrimeLongLocation() != null && crime.getCrimeLongLocation().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0))
```

This says that either `crimeLatLocation` is not `null` and not zero or `crimeLongLocation` is not `null` and not `zero`.

When you use `&` then both sides of the expression are evaluated, when you use `&&` then the test is short circuited if the first part of the expression is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a check for null values before the comparison. You may use this function for the comparison.

```
/** This method compares 2 BigDecimal objects for equality. It takes care of null object and that was the necessity of having it.
 * To use this function most efficiently pass the possibly null object before the not null object.
 * @param pNumber1
 * @param pNumber2
 * @return boolean
 */
public static boolean isEqual(BigDecimal pNumber1, BigDecimal pNumber2)
{
    if ( pNumber1 == null )
    {
        if ( pNumber2 == null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    if ( pNumber2 == null)
        return false;
    return pNumber1.compareTo(pNumber2)==0;
}
```